# Siunitx detects global font instead of local font

Tags: fonts, siunitx

I am typesetting my text in roboto and for the content of my tables I am using robotocondensed and it works fine. However, I am using siunitx for formatting a few of my columns and instead of robotocondensed these columns are typeset in roboto instead. How can I have siunitx detect my local font?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\robotocondensed
\begin{tabular}{r S[table-format=2.0, detect-all]}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Table}\\
\hline
{r} & {S} \\
44 & 44 \\
23 & 23\\
38 & 38\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: siunitx font problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can help `siunitx` by declaring `text-rm=\robotocondensed` in addition to `detect-all`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\robotocondensed
\begin{tabular}{r S[table-format=2.0,detect-all,text-rm=\robotocondensed]}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Table}\\
\hline
{r} & {S} \\
44 & 44 \\
23 & 23\\
38 & 38\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]